# Debugger-checked code shows correct return value in console.log, so why am I returning undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to determine if a passed-in array is Ascending, Descending, Rotated Ascending, or Rotated Descending. Although the now commented out `console.log("RA");` near the end of the overall function shows "RA" when an appropriate string is passed into the parameters for the parent `solve` function, return "RA" is returning `undefined`. The sample array I used for the `arr` parameter in an invocation of `solve` in the console is [4,5,6,1,2,3], a Rotated Ascending array.

I've tried declaring variables and using them in place of the literal return values, and have declared them in several different locations. I have checked out and followed relevant Stack Overflow posts.

```
function solve(arr){

  let asc = arr.every(function (x, i) {
          return i === 0 || x >= arr[i - 1];
      });

  let desc = arr.every(function (x, i) {
          return i === 0 || x <= arr[i - 1];
      });

  if (asc){
    return "A"
  }
  if (desc){
    return "D"
  }
  if (!asc || !desc){
      arr.forEach(function(el, i){

        let rtdAsc = "RA"
        let rtdDesc = "RD"

        let ascFind = arr.find(function(el, i){
          return el >= arr[i - 1]
          })

        let descFind = arr.find(function(el, i){
          return el <= arr[i - 1];
          })

        if (ascFind && descFind){

          if (el === ascFind && arr[i] === el && arr[i+1] > ascFind){  
            return rtdAsc
              // console.log("RA")
          } else if (el === ascFind && arr[i] === el && arr[i+1] < ascFind){
            return rtdDesc
          }
        }
     })
   } 
} 
~~~~~~~~~~~

I expect the result of invoking the example `solve([4,5,6,1,2,3]);` to result in "RA" through return statements, as it does successfully through `console.log("RA");`
```

Comment: can we have sample array ? to start with your problem

Comment: Sure, Dupinder. I showed one in the introduction and at the end of my post: [4,5,6,1,2,3]. This should return "RA", for rotated ascending.  For ascending ("A"), you can use [1,2,3,4,5]; for descending ("D"), you can use [9.8.7.6.5], and for rotated descending, ("RD"), you can use [5,4,9,8,7,6] as samples.

Comment: you're returning inside callback to `forEach`, did you return outside? Can't see any in your code. If there is no return javascript implicitly returns `undefined`

Comment: I don't have any outside callbacks, but I am explicitly returning "RA" or "RD" at the end of the relevant if statements within the forEach callback. I don't suppose that does it, does it?

Comment: I'll try to add explicit returns outside of the if blocks and outside of the forEach callback, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the part where you have `console.log("RA")` and `return "RA"` is **inside** the function inside `arr.forEach(..)`. Thus, you are correctly returning "RA" to the function inside `forEach`, but not returning anything to `solve`.

To resolve this, put a `retVal` before the `forEach` function. See below.

```js
function solve(arr) {

  let asc = arr.every(function(x, i) {
    return i === 0 || x >= arr[i - 1];
  });

  let desc = arr.every(function(x, i) {
    return i === 0 || x <= arr[i - 1];
  });

  if (asc) {
    return "A"
  }
  if (desc) {
    return "D"
  }
  
  let retVal = "none";
  if (!asc || !desc) {  
    arr.forEach(function(el, i) {
      let rtdAsc = "RA"
      let rtdDesc = "RD"

      let ascFind = arr.find(function(el, i) {
        return el >= arr[i - 1]
      })

      let descFind = arr.find(function(el, i) {
        return el <= arr[i - 1];
      })

      if (ascFind && descFind) {
        if (el === ascFind && arr[i] === el && arr[i + 1] > ascFind) {
          console.log("RA");
          retVal = "RA";
          return; //not exactly necessary
        } 
        else if (el === ascFind && arr[i] === el && arr[i + 1] < ascFind) {
          retVal = "RD";
          return; //not exactly necessary
        }
      }
    })
  }
  
  return retVal;
}

console.log(solve([4,5,6,1,2,3]));
```

Comment: Thanks, @Samleo, worked perfectly! I should have thought to make a variable and set it to the correct return value depending on the condition, but then return it at the end of the parent function. If I may be so bold, why is `return;` needed at the end of each of the relevant if blocks?

Comment: Wait.. actually it's not useful at all, unless you have something outside of your `if` `else` loops.. Good question btw.